# Tor in command prompt

Tags: command-line, tor

Is there any way to use tor in terminal (or any other software like tor in command-line). I need this for updating my Ubuntu, as my network not allows to download more than 20MB file. Because of this I have to download files which are more than 20MB in size using tor-browser one by one.

Please let me know any other way to solve this.

Answer (score 5):

Use `torify`.

```
$ man torify
torify is a simple wrapper that attempts to find the best underlying Tor wrapper available on a system. It calls torsocks or tsocks with a tor specific configuration file.
```

E.g. to update and upgrade your packages:

```
sudo torify apt-get update && sudo torify apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Tor-Browser, you need to install `proxychains` and config it by editing the last line of `/etc/proxychains.conf`, this way:

```
socks5  127.0.0.1 9150
```

If you are using tor, so follow @OrangeTux answer.

---

> Please let me know any other way to solve this.

**apt-get** can resume previous downloads. so you can run it frequently. `cron` can repeat the update command for you

`sudo crontab -e`

```
0 */8 * * * /usr/bin/apt-get update; 
*/5 * * * *  /usr/bin/apt-get --force-yes dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `torsocks`

Usage:

`torsocks <application>`

For using this by default, you must already have tor running & listening on localhost, port 9050.